# Teamcity and Browserstack Integration

Tags: teamcity, browserstack

We have some Browserstack C# tests. We have a Teamcity Server, As per Browserstack documentation they have integration with Jenkins, Travis CI, Circle CI. How can i integrate it with Teamcity, I think we can execute using command line. All are windows environments.

Answer (score 2):

They do have a TeamCity Plugin: https://www.browserstack.com/automate/teamcity